# NSPredicate type search is available in Java/Android or not?

Tags: java, android, ios, nspredicate

In the IOS, we need to search an item or name easily find using the NSPredicate on NSArray or collection. This NSPredicate is executing very faster and give the results exactly few seconds

In the Android or Java any NSPredicate type search available? Can you please suggest.

I have LiSt object, It contains "n" number of objects. So, I want search an item name or value is exist in this object or not. If the item is exist to get those items. In IOS it is easy to get the Items using the NSPredicate.

So using java is it possible to fetch the item in the List object. When we use the default for loop it takes lot of time to execute and find the elements.

Comment: Java works differently. In Java you can use `List.contains()` to find if the list contains an object.

Comment: @Vlad i don't know object referece using the List contains.
for example, i have object like "Person"
id, name, email, address- these are the fields. 
so i want to search the person details using the "email"
So, how can i get the details using using the email for the list object?

Comment: `NSPredicate` simply iterates the array; it is less code to write but its execution shouldn't be any faster than a linear search of an array.  Can you show the code you are using in Java?

Comment: `i don't know object referece` what does it mean? Why you don't know it?

Comment: @VladMatvienko `contains` tells you if some object (to which you hold a reference) exists in the `List`; `NSPredicate` is used to identify objects that match some condition (e.g.  in a `List<Person>` give me the objects where the `surname` property is *smith*)

Comment: @VladMatvienko, I update my comment, can you please check and update your suggestion.

Comment: @Paulw11, ok, got it now. lakshmanbob Java 8 has the lambda feature, which is probably what you need.

Comment: @Paulw11, Can you please give one sample example, how we can achieve this. If possible share some example url. Thanks for your reply

Comment: There are 11 answers on the duplicate, all with code.  There is no simple equivalent.  If your data is sorted by the field that you are interested in then you can use a binary search, but otherwise you need to perform a linear search, which is basically a for.. loop or an iterator

Comment: @Paulw11, Why you make this question as Duplicate. your given suggestion url it is using the For loop for checking the object. But, it kills the performance of the search, If we need to check each and every object contain the values it take lot of time. For example if the object contains multiple collection objects, then what will be happen to search?

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate because it is a duplicate.  An array is not a very efficient data structure for searching.  As I said, your only options are binary search if it is ordered or linear search if not; `NSPredicate` merely performs a linear search and saves you from writing the loop yourself; there is no magic.  If your comparison isn't performant then you should look at your comparison code.

Comment: @Paulw11, My question is there any NSPredicate type of search is available in JAVA / Android? If we use basic for loop, then the search will delay to find he exact object and storing the another collection for finding all the objects. Again it should be allocating the memory for another object to store each and every finding element

Comment: @Paulw11, the Given Answer is not acceptable for th Duplicate question you suggested. because we need to achieve the faster search in collections. How can we achieve the results is their any solution for this?

Comment: How many times can I tell you, there is no magic.  NSPredicate is a linear search; that is pretty much the only option you have for Arrays.  Java does not have an NSPredicate equivalent; you need to write your own code.  If you need a faster search then you should consider building a more appropriate data structure or look at the comparison operator you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152511/discussion-between-paulw11-and-lakshmanbob).